# Purchase order email links are broken odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

When creating a Purchase order and send by email the link (view purchase order) to the PO inside the email sent to vendors, it does not work.
When I open this link (view purchase order), it gives me an error 
URL not found:
http://localhost:8012/mail/view?res_id=9&model=purchase.order&access_token=6ceaa079-11eb-4537-836c-6c3b9fc2c27b

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1):

Check that your system parameter web.base.url is set to your publicly accessible address, not localhost. You can find this setting in Odoo menu Settings/Technical/System Parameters. The menu is accessible when you are in developer mode.

A not always known Odoo feature is that by default the url-setting updates automatically when you login with administrator account.  If you login to Odoo with a non public address, e.g. localhost, it will result to wrong addresses for links. To prevent this you can freeze the updates by creating a parameter web.base.url.freeze with value True, and update the web.base.url in parameters with the correct url.

So, I wouldn’t say Odoo purchase order links are broken. If you have localhost set in parameters, this is the intended way of working. The localhost address is, like the name implies, just a local host. You or your vendor cannot access your Odoo server with localhost links anywhere else than on your Odoo server.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have single db in your system or use -d parameter while starting odoo server

start odoo service using

```
python3 odoo-bin -d your_db_name
```

this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the code

```
python3 odoo-bin -d your_db_name
```

added to the odoo config file?

Comment: What if it is? What if not? How does this question answer the question or solve the problem. If you intend this to be an answer in the shape of a rhetoric question... well that risks being confused with a question, which is not an accepted answer. So I recommend to avoid questions in answers.

Comment: It would also help with seeing the usefulnes of your answer, if you could make more obvious the difference to other existing answers, e.g. the one by Alphesh Valaki. As it is, this post gives an impression of being a blundering copy of that other answer.